# having trouble dispalying data in a specific table row using php and mysqli

Tags: php, for-loop, html-table

Hellow i have a problem in displaying reserved room date in a particular table column.
so the expected result is on the first image[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDhjS.png) but i am getting the result on the second image [imagw2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7c1W.png).
I am attaching the code below for help please.
I have written my code with php,html and bootstrap.
Result I want is when the page load it displays reserved date of a given room on a column that match date on  and if the room is not reserved it the column remains  blank.

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','reservations');
$startingDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first sunday of this month -6 days"));
$numberOfDays = 35;
$dates = array();
$weekCounter = 1;
$meetingRow  = '';
$meetingRow   .= '<div class="container">';
$meetingRow   .= '<table class="table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">';
$meetingRow   .= '<tbody>';




for ($i = 0; $i <= $numberOfDays - 1; $i++) {

    $date    = date('m/j/Y', strtotime("$startingDay +$i days"));
    $dates[] = $date;

if (date('l', strtotime($date)) == "Monday") {

    $meetingRow   .= '<tr><td colspan="8"></td></tr>';
    $meetingRow   .= '<tr>';
    $meetingRow   .= '<th>Week ' .  $weekCounter++ . '</th>';
}

$meetingRow    .= '<th>';
$meetingRow    .= '<p>' . $date. '</p>';
$meetingRow    .= '<p>' . date('l', strtotime($date)). '</p>';
$meetingRow    .= '</th>';

if (date('l', strtotime($date)) == "Sunday") {

    $meeting_room_sql = "SELECT id , meeting_room_name  FROM meeting_room";
    $meeting_room_result = mysqli_query($con, $meeting_room_sql);
    // you are to use $meeting_room_result not $meeting_room_sql error occurs in fetching from meeting_room
    while ($meeting_room_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meeting_room_result)) {

        $meeting_room_id    = $meeting_room_row['id'];
        $meeting_room_name  = $meeting_room_row['meeting_room_name'];

        $meetingRow   .= '<tr> 
                             <td> 
                                <div>' . htmlentities($meeting_room_name, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '</div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#meetingModal">Reserve</button>
                             </td>';

        $reserved_sql = "SELECT meeting_room_id, reserved_date FROM meeting WHERE meeting_room_id = {$meeting_room_row["id"]}";
        $reserved_result = mysqli_query($con, $reserved_sql);
        $total_number_of_rows = 7;//As we have 7 days in a week so we have 7 days column

        $RowCounter = 0;
        while ($reserved_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reserved_result)) {
            $RowCounter++;
            $reserved_room_id = $reserved_row['meeting_room_id'];
            $reserved_date    = $reserved_row['reserved_date'];

            if ($reserved_room_id == $meeting_room_id) {
                $meetingRow   .= '<td>' . htmlentities('Meeting Reserved ' . date('m/j/Y', strtotime($reserved_date)), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"). '</td>';
            } else {
                $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>';
            }
        }
        while ($RowCounter < $total_number_of_rows){
                $meetingRow   .= '<td><br /></td>';
                $RowCounter++;
        }

        $meetingRow   .= '<tr>';

    }
    $meetingRow   .= '</tr>';
}



}
$meetingRow   .= '</tbody>';
$meetingRow   .= '</table>';
$meetingRow   .= '</div>';
echo $meetingRow;
?>
</body>
</html>
```